# Problems adding names to THREE.Mesh() while batch loading them

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hello StackOverflow community,

I have problems adding names to THREE.Mesh() while batch loading them.

The code below is having the error:

```
function loadObjects () {
    var objectURL = ["cube", "birdie", "sphere"];

    for (var i = 0; i < objectURL.length; i++) {
        loader.load(
            "Ressources/models/" + objectURL[i] + ".json", 
            function (geometry, materials) {
                var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                mesh.name = String(objectURL[i]);
                scene.add(mesh);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

While loading a single is working fine:

```
function loadObject () {
    var objectURL = ["cube", "birdie", "sphere"];

    loader.load(
        "Ressources/models/" + objectURL[1] + ".json", 
        function (geometry, materials) {
            var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.name = String(objectURL[1]);
            scene.add(mesh);
        }
    );
}
```

All models are loaded and rendered correctly, but it is not possible to use `scene.getObjectByName("birdie");` , when the objects are batch loaded.

About an answer I would be very happy.
Regards Codepuree

EDIT:
Found a way to batch load Objects:

```
var objectURL = ["cube", "birdie", "sphere"];

function loadObjects (iterator) {

    var loadMesh = new THREE.Mesh();
    loader.load(
        "Ressources/models/" + String(vegetationURL[iterator]) + ".json", 
        function (geometry, materials) {
            var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
            loadMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            loadMesh.name = String(vegetationURL[iterator]);
            scene.add(loadMesh);
        }
    );

    loader.onLoadComplete = function () {
        iterator++;
        if (iterator < objectURL.length) {
            loadObjects(iterator);
        }
    }
}

loadObjects(0);
```

The problem was that the loader is loading asynchronously. So the load function is to slow for the for-loop. Loading it in a while loop causes and dead loop. That is why to go with the recursive way.

This works fine now and thanks for the help ther. :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be that when the lambda function is called the value of the i variable is objectURL.length, since the function can be called after the for loop is terminated.

Try this instead:

```
function loadObjects () {
    var objectURL = ["cube", "birdie", "sphere"];

    for (var currentURLId in objectURL){
        loader.load(
            "Ressources/models/" + objectURL[currentURLId] + ".json", 
            function (geometry, materials) {
                var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                mesh.name = String(objectURL[currentURLId]);
                scene.add(mesh);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working since currentURL only returns a number. So the url to the model looks like this, "Ressources/models/0.json" now.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Confused how foreach works in Javascript. Try the edited.

Comment: Still not working scene.getObjectByName("birdie") always returns "undefined"

Comment: Try adding a console.log(currentURLId) in after the for loop and inside the function(geometry, materials), maybe that will reveal the problem. Unfortunately I can't try the script myself.